# Date function format in elegant way?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How write this is more elegant way? This function makes column sorting work. Is another way to do this? If not this fucntion sorting will not work properly :(

```
 getTime1(element: Tsk) {
    const reg = /[\s\.]/

    const [day, month, year, hour, minutes] = element.time.split(reg)

    return new Date(parseInt(year)
      , parseInt(month) - 1,
      parseInt(day),
      parseInt(hour),
      parseInt(minutes)

    ).getTime();

  }
  announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {

    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {

      switch (property) {
        case 'title':
          return item[property].toLocaleLowerCase(); 
          break;
        case 'time':
          return this.getTime1(item);
          break;
 
        default:
          return item[property];
      }
    };

    console.log("============")
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

If I will do this =>

```
getTime1(element: Task) {
emphasized text const reg = /[\s\.]/ 
const [day, month, year, hour, minutes] = element.time.split(reg) 
return new Date(element.time);
 } 

case 'time':
 return item.time;
```

soritng doesn't work properly :(

If I will do such thing:

```
 case 'time': 
return new Date(element.time)
 break;
```

arrow sorting is not working

Comment: You can simple use `new Date(element.time)`.

Comment: getTime1(element: Task) {
    const reg = /[\s\.]/

    const [day, month, year, hour, minutes] = element.time.split(reg)

    return new Date(element.time);

  }
case 'timeStamp':
 return item.timeStamp;

and deosn't work properly :(


If I will do such thing:

case 'time':
          return new Date(element.time)
          break;

arrow sorting is not working

Comment: you can remove `break` after `return`

Comment: try `new Date(element.time).getTime()`

Comment: getTime1(element: Task) {

    new Date(element.time).getTime()

  } soring is not working properly in such way :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example what I mean:

```
 getTime1(element: Tsk) {
    return new Date(element.time).getTime();
  }

  announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {

    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {

      switch (property) {
        case 'title':
          return item[property].toLocaleLowerCase(); 
        case 'time':
          return this.getTime1(item);
        default:
          return item[property];
      }
    };

    console.log("============")
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

the `getTime()` method will be called inside your getTime1 function.

Greetings, Florian

Comment: Sorting is not working in such way:

 getTime1(element: Tsk) {
    const [day, month, year, hour, minutes] = element.time.split(reg)

    return new Date(element.time).getTime();
  }
 case 'time':
          return this.getTime1(item); :(

Comment: So let me see how your "element.time" value looks like.

Comment: this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      console.log(this.getTime1(item))
      console.log("============")
      console.log(item.time)

and in console I have this: 

NaN
 ============
 08.04.2022 16.54
NaN
============
26.01.2022 12.57
NaN
========
18.08.2022 10.52
NaN

Comment: It's a wrong date/time format. So my way cannot work. In this case your code will be the best option.

Comment: One more guestion this sorting works after second click :( any suggestion?

Comment: Without to see the code? No. I need to see the html code and the code which handle the click/call the sort method.